# How to call function defined inside Polymer Custom Element and pass arguments?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have html page using polymer builtin elements along with my customElement(**my-form**)

```
<dom-module id="my-form">
    <template>
        <div>
            <paper-input id="inputName" label="Name" required error-message="Required Input" value="{{data.name}}"> Name </paper-input>
            <paper-input id="inputAge" label="Age" required error-message="Required Input" value="{{data.age}}"> Age </paper-input>
            <div class="rows layout horizontal">
                <paper-button id='cancelBtn' tabindex="0">Cancel</paper-button>
                <paper-button id='saveBtn' tabindex="0">Save</paper-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({

        is: 'my-form',

        created: function() {
            var saveBtn = document.querySelector('#saveBtn');
            saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                document.getElementById('inputName').validate();
                document.getElementById('inputAge').validate();
            });

            //initial value
            this.data = {};  

        },

        properties: {
            data: {
                type: Object,
                value: {},
            },
        }

        //load my-form with data provided  
        refreshFormUI: function(dataReceived) {
            this.data = dataReceived;
            console.log("refreshFormUI() -  name = " + this.data.name);
            console.log("refreshFormUI() -  age = " + this.data.age);
        },

    });
</script>
```

I need to pass the "**data**"object from a external javascript file. I tried the following but I dont see the ***refreshFormUI()*** being called.

***external_js_file.js :***

```
function someEvent() {
    my_form_element = document.querySelector('#my_form_element');
    var mockData = {
        name: "Demo Name",
        age: '20',
    };
    my_form_element.refreshFormUI(mockData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `this.data =` but then in your `console.log` you're using `data.name` instead of `this.data.name`.

Comment: That was a typo when the question was entered into the stackoverflow. I am using this.data.name in the print statements. In the first place I dont even see the string part of log printed console.log("refreshFormUI() -  name = " + data.name);

Comment: There is also a comma missing after the `properties` object.

From what I can tell you're implementing the external API correctly, but some unknown factor is causing it to not behave as expected.  I think the only way we'll be able to determine what that is is to see a complete example.  Can you put together a jsbin?

Comment: Thanks for the help Zikes. The browser was acting weird for some reason. Killing the process helped. Issue resolved. Really appreciate your time and thanks for the verifying the methodology.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you were able to get it resolved!