# Polymer 1.0 - How can I make dom-repeat to work on function call

Tags: dom, polymer-1.0

I have two `custom elements`, one with a list of customers (`customer-list`) and the other is supposed to load selected customer's shipping address (`shipping-address`). An AJAX call is binding the list of customers in `customer-list`. When I click on a customer the list is being filtered based on `e.model.customerid` and creating a new array. I am then assigning this to a custom property in my `shipping-address` element.

Because there could be more than one shipping address for a customer, I am using a `dom-repeat` to bind them. Here is what I want:

1. Let the `dom-repeat` template to bind by a function which I declare in `shipping-address` element, not automatically. This function I want to call after a customer is clicked, record set gets filtered and assigned to the custom property of this element.
2. I want to call that function from my `customer-list` element.

This is what I have tried so far:

**`customer-list`**

```html
_passCustomerIdToGetAdditionalShippingAddress: function (e) {
  var addlShipAddress = document.querySelector("#shipAddl");
  if (addlShipAddress != null) {
    //Filter rows from JSON data based on this customer Id
    //and set the new Array to additional-shipping element's customers property!

    var selectedCustomerId = e.model.item.id;

    //Now filter.....
    var customerId;
    addlShipAddress.fiteredCustomers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.customers.length; i++) {
      customerId = this.customers[i].id;
      if (customerId != selectedCustomerId) continue;
      addlShipAddress.fiteredCustomers.push(this.customers[i]);
      document.querySelector("#shipAddl").bindData();
      break;
    }

    addlShipAddress.customerId = e.model.item.id;
  }
}
```

**`shipping-address`**

```html
<dom-module id="additional-shipping-address">
  <template>
    <style>
        :host
        {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
      <div id="testd">{{fiteredCustomers}}</div>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{fiteredCustomers}}">
          
      </template>
  </template>
    <script>
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            Polymer({
                is: 'additional-shipping-address',

                properties: {
                    fiteredCustomers: {
                        type: Array,
                        value: [],
                        notify: true
                    },

                    customerId: {
                        type: String,
                        notify: true
                    }
                },

                bindData: function () {
                    alert("I have called from outside with value: " + value);
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

1. Console error shows `document.querySelector("#shipAddl").bindData(); is not a function`
2. I have no idea about how to bind a `dom-repeat` through a function. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170930/how-to-call-function-defined-inside-polymer-custom-element-and-pass-arguments) post.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, your `<shipping-address>` is within a template in `<customer-list>`.
If thats so then you could not call an element('#shipAddl') that is inside a template dom-repeat from the place template is running. There could be multiple `<shipping-address>` tags with the same id or even none which could be raising the issue.